# How to get an event registration invoice to the right person?

Tags: civievent, invoice, participants

On a site that I manage we encourage our member contacts to set up and use a user account. This enables us to use automatically applied discount codes for events. We often have a situation where an administrator from one our member organisations is registering multiple people for an event, but not registering themselves.

This ends up with something of a mess in terms of the invoice for the event registrations. The person doing the registration receives nothing, even though they are logged in and therefore presumably known to CiviCRM. Civi assumes that the first registered participant is making the contribution (not the person making the payment), and so the invoice is incorrect, and a copy of this invoice is then sent to everyone other than the person doing the registration. All very messy.

I'd love to have scenario whereby the person making the registrations (regardless of whether they include themselves as a participant) is the person - and the only person - that gets an invoice, and everyone else just gets a notification to confirm that they have registered.

Answer (score 3):

This is a question that comes up quite a lot (assistants registering their bosses, parents registering their kids for summer camps, etc) and there isn't a good solution currently. It would be a great feature if someone wanted to take it on or fund it.

One option is to use a free event fee or price set option that is just for the person who is doing the registering (something like Option A, Option B, I'm just registering other people). Then the person doing the registering is "registered" for the event, but you don't treat that registration option as a real registration — but the downside is this can make registration limits more complicated than they would be otherwise and makes searching and reports more of a pain.

The other option is to use a Webform without registering the first contact for the event and then send the email you want to send via the Webform.